# UIActivityIndicatorView floating above a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a UIActivityIndicatorView for refreshing content on my table, it is centered in the view like so:

```
//Start activity indicator
        UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        indicator.center=self.view.center;
        CGRect frame = indicator.frame;
        frame.origin.x = (self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - frame.size.width / 2);
        frame.origin.y = (self.view.frame.size.height / 2 - frame.size.height / 2)-self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height-20;
        indicator.frame = frame;
        [self.view addSubview:indicator];
        [indicator startAnimating];
```

However at the moment it scrolls with the table, is it possible to get it to float above the table so it remains centered as a user scrolls? I tried adding it to the table superview but that didn't work. Any pointers would be really appreciated! thanks

Comment: What is the table superview? Are you using a table view controller? Is the navigation bar a suitable alternTive for you?

Comment: Try bringsubViewtofront after adding it to view

Comment: @Wain I never considered using the navigation bar for it before. Is it difficult to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are using a `UITableViewController` if that is the case, I would recommend using a `UIViewController` instead. This will give you the ability to add a `UIView` over the top of your `UITableView` to hold your `UIActivityIndicatorView` You will also be able to easily lay it out in storyboard and position it where you want and it will not move with the table scroll as it is it's own view.  As a general rule I try not to ever use a `UITableViewController` because it limits you in situations like this.

Comment: Thanks for this, tried the other methods and seems it will be the only way. I think I will stay away from UITableVIew controller in the future. Does it have any advantages over a standard UIVIewController with a table inside?

Comment: @KexAri No, the `UITableViewController` gets Inheritance from the `UIViewController` so you are not losing anything, in fact you gain more flexibility.  I learned this the hard way early on when I too go stuck and then had to redo my table views....

Comment: Yeah, you lose a lot of function. All a UITableViewController does is prevent you from having to manually connect a data source and delegate.

Answer (score 4):

You can add any type of view "on top" of any tableview, navigation controller or any other simply by adding the created view via a subview very similar to your code, but with the proper root view. Just make you clearly identify the desired root view.

For example, here is how I implement my subviews on top of my navigation controller in one of my apps:

```
...
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:indicator];
...
```

Comment: This is an excellent tip, works great with UITableViewController and also works with programmatically added constraints. Just use the navigationcontroller.view in the constraint too, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
   initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
  spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
  spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
  [self.view addSubview:spinner];
  [spinner startAnimating
```

];

Answer (score 0):

You can add the indicator to the super view of your tableView but, if it doesn't work out, you can also add the activity indicator on the UIWindow of your application. Following is the code:

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]; // this gives you the current window of the application.
[keyWindow addSubview:indicator]; // add the indicator on the window.
```

Once the work is done, remove the activity indicator from the window by using

```
[indicator removeFromSuperView];
indicator = nil;
```

Comment: I tried this, no error messages but the indicator just doesn't show at all